# Visual Studio 2015 throw exception in Try Catch block

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 always throw exception in debug mode, even if error is handled in Try Catch block, which is very annoying. Could You tell me why is this happening? I dont know how to switch this off..

Comment: maybe because an actual exception is thrown?. Post your code please

Comment: You should provide a specific example. This question will probably be deleted due to its wide range.

Comment: If you catch the `Exception`, you have to do something that resolves it.  This can be an empty statement in some cases, though that is usually a sign that your `try/catch` is doing flow control which is bad juju.  The `catch` exists to give you a chance to resolve the problem.

Comment: But what example? This is problem with a debugger. I have a lot of "Try catch" blocks and in every single one this is happening. Visual Studio is ignoring "try catch" and always break application if error occurs in "try" statement.

Comment: You're probably confused.  An exception is *always* thrown no matter whether it's debug mode or not.  Your debugger will break on the exception if you have configured it to do so which doesn't mean that the exception *isn't* being thrown when you're not debugging.  I don't think I'm being as clear as I intend...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to Exception Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on my visual studio) and tick or untick the kind of exception you want to break on when they are thrown.

**Edit explanation**
When you run in debug mode, Visual Studio believe that notifying when an exception is raised is a good way to help the developper. Even if the exception is caught.
The Exception Settings allows you to change this behaviour by choosing what the kind of exception should be notified or not.

Comment: That's fine, but you need to explain *why*.  The OP is obviously confused about this whole notion, so this answer doesn't really do much to help that.  Good answers should *teach*, not just serve to slap a bandaid on something and move on.

Comment: Thank You Bruno for help and explanation. In "Exception Settings" is button "Restore list to default settings", after I clicked this everything works normal.

Comment: Yes, 45 seconds left ;)

Comment: This finally explains **why** VS does this. Thanks! Now I'm no longer believing that my VS settings are screwed.

Comment: Disabling exceptions entirely prevents both handled/unhandled exceptions. The question calls for understanding how to disable handled exceptions from being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled [first chance exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/) handling.

To disable it open Debug->Windows->Exception Settings and uncheck the exceptions you don't want to break the debugging when thrown. Check the link for more details.